# Opening a new Safari window with Alfred AppleScript opens 2 windows

Tags: applescript, alfred

When I run this script from Alfred (using the text "nsafari", and Safari is quit (not in the dock), two Safari windows will pop up. When I run it from the Script Editor, it will sometimes open up two windows, but sometimes not. (This also happens with my new Safari window script as well).

```
if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "Safari"
        make new document
        activate
    end tell
else
    tell application "Safari" to activate
end if
```

Why does it open two windows only from Afred? And how do I make it only create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but after two years, the problem I reported above does not seem to happen any more...

(and yes this is not a very satisfying answer)